# Number of ways in which $8$ persons can be seated in three different taxis.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of ways in which 8 person can be seated in three different taxies each having 3 seats for passenger and duly numbered. internal arrangement matters.

**My approach:**
Method (1):- Since seats are numbered, we can consider all seats to be different. I want to seat eight persons on $9$ seats, which can be done by $C(9,8) \cdot 8! = 9!$.

Method (2):- First, I'll make $3$ unnumbered group of sizes $3,3,2$, which can be done in $\frac {8!}{3! \cdot 3! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$ ways. Now I will distribute these group to $3$ taxis, which can be done in $3!$ ways. And internal arrangement of seats in the taxis can be done in $3!$, $3!$, $2!$. So final answer will be $$\frac {8!}{3! \cdot 3! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} \cdot {3! \cdot 3! \cdot 3! \cdot 2!}$$  That is equal to $3 \cdot 8!$.

What is going wrong in second method?
I want to know mistake in second problem.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three seats available in the taxi which holds only two people.  The two people in that taxi can be seated in $3! = 3 \cdot 2$ ways since there are three ways to seat the younger person and two ways to seat the older person.  Replacing the factor of $2!$ by $3!$ in your second method yields
$$\frac{8!}{3!3!2!2!} \cdot 3! \cdot 3! \cdot 3! \cdot 3! = 8! \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 9!$$
in agreement with the correct answer you obtained using your first (simpler) method.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the empty seat to be person number $9$, then you quickly get $9!$ as your answer.

The other answer treats the cab with 2 people as a 2-seater, and therefore counts:

$(A,B,*), (A,*,B), (*,A,B)$

as the same arrangement.

Comment: For the simplest explanation, +1.